# smart pointer and QThread issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, qt5, c++14

At some point in my code I have:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Beacon *beacon = new Beacon(beg, end);
beacon->moveToThread(thread);
```

And the other day I was reading about this thing called smart pointer. If I understand, it might fit in the peace of code above, I tried:

```
std::unique_ptr<QThread> thread {new QThread};
std::unique_ptr<Beacon> beacon {new Beacon(beg, end)};
beacon->moveToThread(thread);
```

This, led to:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'std::unique_ptr<QThread>' to 'QThread *'
    beacon->moveToThread(thread);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `moveToThread(thread.get())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a raw pointer (`Qthread *`) to `moveToThread`. You have to use either `unique_ptr::release` (`thread.release()`) or `unique_ptr::get` (`thread.get()`) to get the raw pointer, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But passing the raw pointer am I still secure (using the benefits of smart pointer)?

Comment: Yes, if you use get(), your unique_pointer will maintain it's ownership a(e.g. should delete the managed data at some point). release() doesn't do that though ... @KcFnMi

Answer (score 3):

You can use QScopedPointer instead of std::unique_ptr. [Example](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/QThread-with-moveToThread_console.git)

Answer (score 0):

In my project, i use qthread in this way

> Another way to make code run in a separate thread, is to subclass
> QThread and reimplement run()

and this is my use of `std::unique_ptr` and `Qthread`

```
std::unique_ptr<QThread> top_thread{new  mythread(nullptr, &numTop, allPics[0], 1, shape, type, containEF, false)};
top_thread->start();
```

it works fine

**in your case, you can do this**

you can implement this `std::unique_ptr<Beacon> beacon {new Beacon(beg, end)};` in the subclassed `run` member function. and then just use thread->start()

```
class thread:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    thread(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~thread();
    virtual void run();

public:
    

};
```

and in the `run()`

```
void mythread::run() {
    std::unique_ptr<Beacon> beacon {new Beacon(beg, end)};
}
```

then you can simple use `thread->start()`

Comment: It's hard to see how your code snippet applies to the specific question as there's no explanation of what each argument does or where the person asking the question was going wrong.

Comment: yes you're right, i have made it more clear now, the main point is since there are two ways to use thread in QT， the first is his using moveToThread，and second is subclass QThread and reimplement run()，which is more flexible